# Как заставить TableColumn принимать ширину по содержимому?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

Как сделать так, чтобы TableColumn в TableView принимал ширину по содержимому(по максимальной длине содержимого ячейки в данном столбце)?
 Что-то вроде fit to content. Искал в интернете ответы, но ничего путного не нашел, хотя сам TableView имеет такой функционал - при даблклике на сепаратор заголовков столбцов, левый столбец растягивается до содержимого - именно то, что нужно, но как программно вызвать это не нашел.

Answer (score 1):

Сам этим не занимался, но путь примерный укажу:
Можно вставить произвольную политику изменения размера.

```
tableView.setColumnResizePolicy(Callback<TableView.ResizeFeatures,java.lang.Boolean> callback)
```

Знаю, выглядит страшно, но не так так страшен черт как его название, вот тут мы его определяем:

```
static class ColumnResizePolicy implements Сallback<TableView.ResizeFeatures, Boolean>
{


    @Override
    public Boolean call(ResizeFeatures arg0)
    {
    //А тут из arg0 можно получить как таблицу так и колонку, для которой она применяется.
    }
}
```